# Approximation of F using Hooke's Law

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

This problem is on a practice exam paper and I can't figure out the code

> Recall Hooke's law, that states that for a given spring, there is a constant
>   k such that when the spring is in equilibrium `F = kx` where `F` is the force pulling at the free end, and `x` is the displacement of the end from its original position.
>
> Assume that you want to estimate the constant k for a given spring, and
>   that you have two Python lists, forces and displacements where the
>   ith entries correspond to each other.
>   Write a Python program that:
>
> 1. Plots the force on the y-axis and the displacement on the x-axis.
> 2. Calculates a linear approximation of `F` as a function of x and plots
>      the approximation.

So far I have:

```
import pylab
pylab.plot(displacements, forces, "bo")
pylab.xlabel("Displacement")
pylab.ylabel("Force")
pylab.show()
```

For the first part which I think is right.

For the second part, I have:

```
avgF = sum(forces)/len(forces)
avgX = sum(displacements)/len(displacements)
K = avgF/avgX
pylab.plot(displacements,K*displacements)
```

Which I'm really unsure of, I can't check the values because I don't have the lists to try out the code.

Comment: Why not invent some values yourself. E.g. `displacements = np.array([1,1.6,3,4.5,6.2,8.2,9]); 
forces = np.array([4,7,11,14,18,25,27])`. Using your code this gives you a nice diagram, which is correct. Now we can't know the exact requirements of "linear approximation"; usually one would rather do a least-squares fit, but if that isn't specified in the task, your solution is equally correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think your code is fine. You could always generate some random sample data and test it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate random sample data
N = 20
k_theoretical = 3
displacement = np.arange(N)
force = k_theoretical * displacement + np.random.normal(size=N)

# Calculate constant for Hooke's law
avgF = sum(force) / len(force)
avgX = sum(displacement) / len(displacement)
k_calculated = avgF / avgX

# Plot data points and line
plt.plot(displacement, force, "bx")
plt.plot(displacement, k_calculated * displacement, "r-",
    label="k = {:.2f}".format(k_calculated))
plt.xlabel("Displacement")
plt.ylabel("Force")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

By the way, if you're using NumPy Arrays for your data, you could calculate the average with

```
avgF = force.mean()
avgX = displacement.mean()
```

Comment: Thanks! I think my lecturer expects us to use a least squares fit for this question but I don't know how to do that and I'm afraid a question might come up in the exam specifying that method, do you know how I'd go about doing it that way? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

#### Least squares fit

You have *N* readings, *fₙ* and *d⁩ₙ* with *n = 1, …, N*, the force and the displacement, and you don't have *k*, the spring constant... The ideal relationship is *k dₙ = fₙ* but we know that, due to measurement uncertainties, the ideal relationship is never exactly verified and we have an error, *eₙ = k dₙ - fₙ*.  The best that we can do is to minimize some measure of the error...

After mentioning that another popular choice is to minimize the maximum of the absolute value of the error, let's see what happens when we try to minimize the sum of the squares of the errors (or, from another point of view, the length of the error vector in a *N*-dimensional space):

```
    S = sum((k dₙ - fₙ)²) = sum(k²dₙ² - 2 k dₙ fₙ + fₙ²) =
      = k² sum(dₙ²) - 2 k sum(dₙ fₙ) + sum(fₙ²).
```

In this expression the only variable is *k*, so to find the minimum we just have to zero out the derivative of *S* wrt to *k*. Using a little algebra

```
    S' = 2 k sum(dₙ²) - 2 sum(dₙ fₙ) =0 ⇒ k = sum(dₙ fₙ)/sum(dₙ²)
```

(remember that *k* is not the spring constant but rather *our best estimate* of the spring constant).

In Python

```
f, d = [...], [...]
...
k = sum(dn*fn for dn,fn in zip(d,f) / sum(dn**2 for dn in d)
```